# How can I fix "Network is obsolete" in unity 2019.1.9?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I made a game and use ["Energy bar toolkit"](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/energy-bar-toolkit-7515) unity package in unity `5.3.4`
so I have "Network" contax Error when I transfer from unity `5.3.4` to unity `2019.1.9`
because network removed in unity `2018.2` and newer

How can I repair This Error?

Answer (score 2):

#### In general

You shouldn't make huge jumps in Unity versions. `5.3.4` is from 2015, `2019.1.9` from mid of 2019 ... you can expect a lot of API changes between over 3 years apart software versions in general.

You should rather make incremental step-wise updates and also when you do be aware of what changes each version in between brings.

When using an [asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/energy-bar-toolkit-7515) from the Asset-Store that says Unity version `5.2.1 or higher` ... I would suspect maintanace kind of stopped quite a while ago and there will at minimum be some severe hickups in implementing it into most latest Unity versions over 3 years later.

#### UNet is obsolete

This has been **[known for quite a while**](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001252086-UNet-Deprecation-FAQ) already. It will soon be (almost) completely deprecated.

[image]

#### The fix for now

In order to still be able to use the HLAPI for now you have to go to the [PackageManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.package-manager-ui@latest/index.html) (<kbd>Window</kbd> →<kbd>Package Manager</kbd> ) and find and import the [`Multiplayer HLAPI`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi@latest/index.html) package.

See [Packages](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Packages.html) for more information about the `PackageManager` and packages in general.

---

There might still be some changes to do and I'm not saying this will completely fix that asset. If you still have trouble you should rather directly contact the [makers](http://madpixelmachine.com/) of the [asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/energy-bar-toolkit-7515).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this method works with you, unity added a replacement for unity network via the PackageManager so we want to auto-convert the old Multiplayer to the new Networking System.

First, get back to the project on unity 5.3.4, and start upgrading it gradually, 
First, open the project on **Unity 5.5.6** then **2017.1.5f1** then **2017.4.32f1** and so on, open it on the first release and upgrade it to the LTS release, **2018.1.9f2** to **2018.4.10f1** then open it on the **2019** version.

and be sure all plugins are updated. hope that help

Comment: What?????????????????????This is hardly so i have not this versions

Answer (score 0):

I Do not understand this answers and need for this package("Energy bar toolkit") only
if I can  change Network with other context ,it maybe work
I wrote a letter to maker asset ad am wait for answer