# Unity Network Script Issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer

I have a multiplayer game that was built using the Unity editor but from like 8 years ago. The networking stuff has been updated inside the editor and I am being haunted by a single error as follows:

Assets\General Scripts\Move.cs(58,33): error CS0619: 'Network' is obsolete: 'The legacy networking system has been removed in Unity 2018.2. Use Unity Multiplayer and NetworkIdentity instead.'

I have been playing with this for a couple hours now, and it seems that I am just missing a 'using' statement. Below is the code that is causing the error, any pointers would be helpful.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {
     Vector3 velocity;
     int speed;
     string playerClone;
     GameObject Player;
     Transform avatar0;
     public int health;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
     {
          speed = 3;
          health = 100;
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
     {
          if (health <= 0)
          {
               die();
          }
          if (Input.GetKey("up"))
          {
               velocity = Vector3.forward * speed;
               transform.Translate(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
          }

          if (Input.GetKey("down"))
          {
               velocity = Vector3.back * speed;
               transform.Translate(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
          }
          if (Input.GetKey("left"))
          {

               transform.Rotate(0, -2, 0);
          }

          if (Input.GetKey("right"))
          {
               transform.Rotate(0, 2, 0);
          }
    }

     void OnLoaded()
     {

          Network.Instantiate(avatar0, transform.position, transform.rotation, 0);
          playerClone = "Player(Clone)";

          Player = GameObject.Find(playerClone);
     }

     void OnPlayerDisconnected (Network player)
     {
          Move.Instantiate(Player);
          Network.DestroyPlayerObjects(player);
     }

     void die()
     {
          Destroy(this.gameObject);
     }
}
```

Comment: Not quite. The error is telling you what the issue is. You are in a version where the code you are trying to use is no longer supported. You either need to downgrade your version of unity or refactor your code to use the newer networking methods it is specifying.

Comment: Correct, as stated I am aware the network stuff in Unity is updated. the specific line that is giving me issue is this one: void OnPlayerDisconnected (Network player). I have attempted to replace 'Network' with 'NetworkIdentity', but I just get an error about possibly missing a 'using' or 'assembly' reference. So that obviously won't help me, which brings me to the conclusion that I am missing something else but I am not able to figure out what it is.

Comment: Everything using `Network` is not longer going to work. The error is pretty direct about that. The entire `OnPlayerDisconnect` and `OnLoaded` seem to be using the Network methods that are no obsolete. If you want to see everything that will no longer work, check the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.html). Everything that derives from these methods or from Networking is not going to work. [MLAPI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNet.html) is the new networking solution, but its still not done. I'd use photon or something equivalent for now.

Comment: Yes, that is what you said the first time. I know what my problem is but not how to fix it, I have attempted to use the recommended NetworkIdentity, this is where I get the idea that I am missing a 'using' statement since I get a second error stating as much. As I said I have been playing with this for almost 3 hours now and I can't figure out what is missing.

Comment: So the short answer is that script can't be upgraded to work?

Comment: It can be refactored meaning it has to be rewritten. What you currently have is using an outdated no longer existing Unity Networking. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263741/how-can-i-fix-network-is-obsolete-in-unity-2019-1-9). I would try to import the new Unity Networking package and see what errors it gives then.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, I wasn't able to find the package mentioned in the other thread so I will just scrap what I have and start over. Looks like it won't be worth it to refactor since EOL for that stuff is this year anyway. That's what I get for waiting so long to revisit it.

Comment: I believe it might be due to the package being not being released. Try going to the package manager, then clicking advanced, and then click `Show Preview Packages`. It should show up then.